# HttpClient response after redirect is getting wrong response

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using `HttpClient version 4.2.5` for making post request to URL `http://lirr42.mta.info/index.php`

This url is redirecting to schedules.php and finally
I am expecting the result with all scheduled train timing detail.

After implementing `LaxRedirectStrategy` I am getting correct response code as `200` instead of `302`. But issue is I am not getting response as from `schedules.php` (redirected url) but getting following response from `index.php` (1st url) only parameters what I sent.

> FromStation=56&ToStation=8&RequestDate=09%2F07%2F2013&RequestAMPM=PM&RequestTime=01%3A00&sortBy=1&schedules=schedules

Please help me to resolve issue.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    getPageHttpClient("http://lirr42.mta.info/index.php");
}

public static String getPageHttpClient(String url) throws IOException {
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    List<NameValuePair> formparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FromStation", "56"));
    formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ToStation", "8"));
    formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("RequestDate", "09/07/2013"));
    formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("RequestAMPM", "PM"));
    formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("RequestTime", "01:00"));
    formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sortBy", "1"));
    formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("schedules", "schedules"));
    UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams, "UTF-8");
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    httppost.setEntity(entity);
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    httpclient.setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy());


    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost, localContext);
    HttpUriRequest currentReq = (HttpUriRequest) localContext.getAttribute( 
            ExecutionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);
    HttpHost currentHost = (HttpHost)  localContext.getAttribute( 
            ExecutionContext.HTTP_TARGET_HOST);
    String currentUrl = currentHost.toURI() + currentReq.getURI();        
    System.out.println(currentUrl);
    System.out.println(response);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
    String str = "";
    if (httpEntity != null) {
        str = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        System.out.println(str);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Response of Program:

```
http://lirr42.mta.info/schedules.php 

HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Date: Fri, 06 Sep 2013 20:01:53 GMT, Server:  Apache/2.2.3 (Linux/SUSE), X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.5, Expires: 0, Cache-Control: no-cache, Pragma: no-cache, Content-Type: text/html, Content-Length: 15832, Age: 1, Via: 1.1 localhost.localdomain]    

FromStation=56&ToStation=8&RequestDate=09%2F07%2F2013&RequestAMPM=PM&RequestTime=01%3A00&sortBy=1&schedules=schedules
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the right response, you're just not printing it correctly.

That's because you're `EntityUtils.toString()` on `entity` instead of `httpEntity`.

Here

```
HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
String str = "";
if (httpEntity != null) {
    str = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

you pass `entity` which is

```
UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams, "UTF-8");
```

ie. the parameters.

Use

```
str = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

to get the `HttpResponse` content.